# "Apart from": exсlusion or inclusion?

Tags: adverbs, ambiguity

Some people say that *apart from* means inclusion (example 1), and some say that it means exclusion (example 2).

> 1. Apart from being a good husband, he is also a good father. It means he is a good husband and a good father.
> 2. Apart from Tom, she invited all the boys. It means she didn't invite Tom.

My questions:

- How to understand what does *apart from* means in one sentence or another?
- Is it best to not use *apart from* in technical writing because of its ambiguity and replace it with *besides* (to denote inclusion) and *except [for]* (to denote exclusion)?

Comment: You have correctly understood "apart from" because of the context. In both cases, "Apart from" can be understood as **If we ignore**: ***If we ignore** [his] being a good husband, he is also a good father.* / **If we ignore** Tom, she invited all the boys. *Is it best to not use the **the phrase "apart from X"** in technical writing?* No, it is not best.

Comment: Thanks, this answers the question.